# How do I get information on a base element? .Children throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, c#-code-model

I am using Visual Studio's CodeModel to gather information on interfaces in the code.

I am able to successfully gather information about the interface using the type `CodeInterface`. This interface exposes a property Bases, which allows me to discover what interfaces my interface inherits from.

However, while I am able to step through the properties or methods of my initial interface using `.Children`. I cannot do the same for the parent interfaces ( a `NotImplementedException` is thrown).

Initially I believed this problem to be because I was using FileCodeModel, so I switched to `Project.CodeModel`:

```
FileCodeModel fileCM =  
        _applicationObject.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel;
```

**My Code:**

```
CodeModel CM = _applicationObject.ActiveWindow.Project.CodeModel;

CodeInterface myInterface = 
    (CodeInterface)CM.CodeTypeFromFullName( "ConsoleApplication8.IWrapper" );

foreach( CodeElement cE in myInterface.Bases ) {
    if( cE is CodeInterface ) {
        string itemName = cE.FullName;
        CodeInterface parentInterface = 
        (CodeInterface)CM.CodeTypeFromFullName( itemName );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the correct property of `CodeInterface` to use is `.Members` (which is still an enumerable set of `CodeElements`)